# Listener for volume button key events

Tags: android, button, callback, keylistener, onkeydown

I am making a library for tracking user events in app. I want to have a callback when user presses volume button twice on the home screen of the app to my library. How can I get the callback without extending activity. onKeyDown works on the Activity only.
I tried

```
    public class SettingsContentObserver extends ContentObserver
{
    int previousVolume;
    Context context;

    public SettingsContentObserver(Context c, Handler handler)
    {
        super(handler);
        context = c;

        AudioManager audio = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        previousVolume = audio.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
        Log.i("myTag", "SettingsContentObserver previousVolume = " + previousVolume);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean deliverSelfNotifications()
    {
        return super.deliverSelfNotifications();
    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange)
    {
        super.onChange(selfChange);

        AudioManager audio = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        int currentVolume = audio.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);

        Log.d("myTag", currentVolume + " currentVolume");

        int delta = previousVolume - currentVolume;

        if (delta > 0)
        {
            Log.i("myTag", delta + " Decreased");
            previousVolume = currentVolume;
        }
        else if (delta < 0)
        {
            Log.i("myTag", delta + " Increased");
            previousVolume = currentVolume;
        }
    }
}
```

This is not calling onChange when there is no change in volume. For example, if the volume is full when user presses the volume up button it is not getting called. Similarly when the volume is 0, and if user presses volume down, it won't get called. How can get the callback?

Comment: can you use dispatchKeyEvent in this class?

Comment: No, We can't. Its same like onKeyDown

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to listen to key events while in the home screen, but there's a way by which you can listen to volume change, using **Content Observer**. It is like a broadcast receiver which is called when changes in content such as volume, contacts, call logs, etc. But this won't work when phone is in sleep.

**Here's the code:**

```
public class Service_VolumeListener extends Service{ 
AudioManager audioManager;
Handler handler;

private ContentObserver volumeObserver = new ContentObserver(handler) {
    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
        super.onChange(selfChange);
        if (audioManager != null) {

            final int volume = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
            Log.d("VOL_STATS", "Volume Changed: " +volume);
        }
    }
};

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);

    Uri uri = Settings.System.getUriFor(Settings.System.VOLUME_SETTINGS[AudioManager.STREAM_RING]);
    getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(uri, true, volumeObserver);

    //Volume listener Registered
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();      

    getContentResolver().unregisterContentObserver(volumeObserver);
    //Volume service unregistered
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {

    return null;
}
}
```

Comment: Settings.System.VOLUME_SETTINGS is no longer supported

Comment: Then try replacing that line with this code "Uri uri = Settings.System.getUriFor("VOLUME_RING");" and let me know if it works

Comment: what error did you get? It works perfectly in my project.